# How to convert sql join into django

Tags: django

I want test case name list by using the above table

**models.py**

```
class TestcaseCache(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')


class KeywordCache(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey('Keyword')
    testcase = models.ForeignKey('TestcaseCache')


class Keyword(models.Model):
    keywordName = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
```

Here i want to sort the KeywordName from Keyword table related to the TestcaseCache table using join

How i convert below sql query into to django

```
SELECT t.name  FROM testcasecache t join keyword k on t.project_id = k.project_id order by t.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select_related()`. Like this manner,

```
names = testcasecache.objects.select_related('keyword').order_by('-name')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Can you tell me the exact query for it..?

Comment: I gave exact query try once.

Comment: FYI, `all()` is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

By using keywordcache table you can fetch the particular keyword of that particular test case
name=testcasecache.objects.filter(keyword=kid,testcase=tid)
where tid is ur testcase id
and kid is your keyword id